# CPT instead of WooCommerce "Product"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, elementor

I have a problem that hopefully you will help me solve.

I'm am pretty new with this job and don't know pretty much anything about coding yet. I built some websites using Elementor but never touched WooCommerce before and now I am working on a real estate website with lots of houses uplouded as a Custom Post Type (which I will call "ANN").

My problem is: my client wants to have a live catalogue of the selling houses for ADS and stuff.

Searching the Web I figured out that WooCommerce is the best way to do it even if I don't need the shopping cart (if you have other ideas are welcome) but as far as I understand WC have ITS OWN CPT "Product" and I wonder how canI set it to use my ANN instead of PRODUCT to the listing?

Is that possible?
The main problem is that there are lots of real estate ads already uplouded so change them is a no go.

I'm using JetEngine plugin for the CPT, Filters, etc.. if this can help somehow.

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, but you're gonna need elementor pro.

You can create all the additional fields for the information you need to be displayed in that post type using ACF.

See this link for more information: [Creating a Field Group](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/)

Make sure your custom post type supports custom fields, if you created it with the CPT UI plugin, you can check that by editing your custom post type and scrolling all the way down. You should see a section with a list of things supported by your custom post type, check custom fields and save.

Then create a template for the custom post type using Elementor's theme builder: [How to Create a WordPress Single-Post Template in Elementor](https://elementor.com/blog/design-your-single-post-template/)

Add the custom fields to the template using the ACF integration with Elementor: [Elementor Integration With ACF](https://elementor.com/help/elementor-acf/)

Lastly, create a custom loop for your custom post type archive using the Elementor custom skin plugin, so yiu can display the custom fields also in the archive if you need to:

[How to display posts in Elementor Pro with your own Design (Elementor Custom Loop)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7QRFgw4DCo)

Comment: Hi, Nicholas, thank you for your answer!

For what I understand, everything I could do with ACF is what I actually already did with  the JetEngine pack creating a new CPT with all the custom fields that I already use in a single post page and listing display.

Thats make me realize that I can make a catalogue the same way I did the rest of the website. Just on larger scale/disposition.
If this is ok for the Ads team.

Thank you for now! I will check it!